# For a certain good, if there is a one-time fixed cost for a consumer to switch to a different firm, then this good is?

Tags: microeconomics

For a certain good, if there is a one-time fixed cost for a consumer to switch to a different firm in a later time, then we say this good is ____ (or has property ___). Examples include

- Consumer: House renter
- Firm: Landlord
- Good: Stays in a house
- One-time Cost: Moving cost

---

- Consumer: Mobile phone user
- Firm: Wireless carrier
- Good: Uses of phone over a carrier network
- One-time Cost: New account activation fee

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The good has a switching cost / is subject to a switching cost. Rarely used: it is a Diamond good. (Referring to the Diamond 1971 paper.)